# Adding Absolute Value To Integral Or Derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In the case of $\int\frac{1}{x}=\ln|x|$ the values that $\ln(x)$ must be positive, hence we put $x$ inside absolute value.

basically we do this for all function that after integration or derivative can be none defined? is there a list of those functions?

Comment: there is no finite list of such function  and therefore no list.

Comment: Values of $\ln$ doesn't have to be positive, just the argument of $\ln$. The identity $\int 1/x=\ln |x|$ can be computed or derived via elementary calculus, but I don't think it's a "general principle".

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is just a trick to glue together two disconnected components of the domain of 1/x. It works because 1/x is an odd function. It would not work for general functions with holes in their domain. Note that we might as well add the constant 5 on the positive real numbers and the constant 7 on the negative ones.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. So it integral should be defined on the same domain. $\ln x$ is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ however $\ln|x|$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

If you encounter a similar function where the integral is not defined on the same domain as the original function you need to think about how it is integrated upon other parts of its domain and what result they would give.

E.g. Lets trying to integrate $f(x)=|x|$. It is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$. Consider its behavior for $x\geq 0$. Here the function is like $x$ so it integrates to $\frac{x^2}{2}$. However for $x\leq0$ it behaves like $-x$ so it integrates to $-\frac{x^2}{2}$. You could define the integral separately for the two halves or we could try to marry the two solutions. Doing so gives: $\frac{x|x|}{2}$.